# Zipping multiple files using TCL's tk_getOpenFile

Tags: shell, compression, tcl

I'm creating a packager in tcl, from which the user may select which files he want to compress into the package.

Problem is, I cannot compress multiple files, when multiple files are selected, the path in the $file variable gets like this : "/home/file.txt /home/file2.txt" So it can't be compressed since the path is not fond.

Is there a way to compress multiple files using the tk_getOpenFile function?

```
set types {
    {{Text Files}       {.txt}        }  
 }
 #Here i'm defining that only .txt files can be selected

set file [tk_getOpenFile -multiple 1 -filetypes $types -parent .] 
#the file chooser function in tcl, where it can be chosen multiple files at once, the path of the files go into the $file variable

exec zip -j package.zip $file 
# A shell script function for zipping the files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec zip -j package.zip {*}$file
```

If you're on Tcl 8.5 or later.

The `{*}` prefix rewrites the invocation so that if the expression after it is a list, each of the elements in that list becomes a word in the invocation.  If the value of `$foo` is `{a b c}` and you invoke `bar abc {*}$foo def`, the actual invocation becomes `bar abc a b c def`.

You shouldn't have any trouble with file names containing spaces, as long as you keep the `-multiple` option on.

Documentation: [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)